# Do i need to create new Callable object for each thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Here are the two options

1) Create one Callable and submit it multiple times

```
Callable<String> callable = new MyCallable();
        for(int i=0; i< 100; i++){
           Future<String> future = executor.submit(callable);
            list.add(future);
        }
```

2) Create multiple Callables for each thread

```
 for(int i=0; i< 100; i++){
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new MyCallable());
        list.add(future);
    }
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: You need different callable objects.

Comment: Thank you . this is what i thought. However there is an example here http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example which confuses me . it uses one callable

Comment: @jn1kk - It depends on what that class does.  There's nothing inherently wrong with invoking the same Callable from multiple threads.

Comment: I doesn't make sense to me. How is it "logically" acceptable to invoke the same Callable with multiple threads? The Callable object has its state while being used by a thread, then a different thread shows up and tries to use that same Callable

Comment: You can use single callable instance if you're not doing same thing in each. There's no state in `Callable`, it's just has to provide implementation of `call()` method. It doesn't matter how many threads use it.

Comment: @john - it only has state if you give it state. And even if you do, you could still make it thread-safe in various ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `MyCallable` is **thread-safe class** then you can reuse the same instance of it, otherwise, you will end up with **race conditions** and inconsistent results.

In other words, if your `MyCallable` **tries to hold any state which is not synchronized properly, then you can't use the same instance**.

For example, the below `MyCallable` class, you can't reuse the same instance across multiple threads (i.e., you can't share it like `executor.submit(singleInstance)`):

```
//Non-Thread Safe Callable implementation
public class MyCallable implements Callable<String> {

    private int i;

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
         i++; //RACE CONDITION
         System.out.println(i);
         return String.valueOf(i);
    }
}
```

Whereas if you replace `int` with `AtomicInteger`, like shown below, then you can reuse the same instance:

```
//Thread Safe Callable implementation
public class MyThreadSafeCallable implements Callable<String> {

    private AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
         int value = i.incrementAndGet();
         System.out.println(value);
         return String.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

So, the important point to note here is that, if you wanted to reuse the same instance of `Callable`, you need to ensure that it is threadsafe. Otherwise, you need multiple `Callable` instances to be submitted to the `ExecutorService`.